# Cosmos DB spatial query using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to query a cosmos db collection using a spatial query. Specifically the `ST_DISTANCE` query. This query works as intended using the `azure-cosmos` Python SDK.

I am looking to use this query via Apache Spark for a more complex query pattern. However, using the `ST_DISTANCE` query in a `SQL` cell in a notebook results in the following error.

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ST_DISTANCE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.
```

The notebook is initialized as follows.

```
# Configure Catalog Api to be used
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog", "com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint", cosmosEndpoint)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountKey", cosmosMasterKey)

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg)\
 .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled", "true")\
 .load()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("outlets")

_______________________________________________________________________

%sql
SELECT * FROM outlets f WHERE ST_DISTANCE(f.boundary, POINT(0,0)) < 600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand from the Cosmos DB Spark connector github repo[1], not all Cosmos DB filter queries are supported via the connector (yet?). So the `ST_DISTANCE` and other filter functions in the spatial family aren't going to work as those aren't predicates that are natively supported by Spark to be pushed down to the database.

Found something that will help sail past this issue at least temporarily. The query config[2] allows sending a custom query directly to Cosmos DB. A temporary view can be built and queried over. This will not work for all use cases, but this solved my issue where I need a single view with distance filtering done. Rest can be handled via Spark SQL.

Refer `spark.cosmos.read.customQuery`[2] in below sample.

```
outlets_cfg = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : cosmosEndpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : cosmosMasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : cosmosDatabaseName,
  "spark.cosmos.container" : cosmosContainerName,
  "spark.cosmos.read.customQuery" : "SELECT * FROM c WHERE ST_DISTANCE(c.location,{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\": [12.832489, 18.9553242]}) < 1000"
}

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**outlets_cfg)\
 .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled", "true")\
 .load()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("outlets")
```

[1] https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12/

[2] https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md#query-config